# Sending event back to event bus using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-event-bridge

I am new to event bus service within AWS.
I am trying to send a event back to event bus using boto3 library.

for some reason I am not finding any logs in cloud watch with respect to the event of event bridge.

Here is what i am trying out:

```
def handler(event, context):
    event_client = boto3.client('events')
    response = event_client.put_events(
                Entries=[
                    {
                        'Source': 'Lambda function get_distance_duration_from_bsig_file',
                        'DetailType': 'Distance and Duration calculated by bsig file',
                        'Detail': json.dumps(event),
                        'EventBusName': 'workflow-notifications-bus'
                        
                    },
                ]
            )
```

In `'Detail'` I am sending in the event that i am getting in from lambda event.

Is there anything that i am missing out?
Also here is the response from put_events

```
{
  "FailedEntryCount": 0,
  "Entries": [
    {
      "EventId": "07f05db5-da9f-74a2-0b81-55c5088895bd"
    }
  ],
  "ResponseMetadata": {
    "RequestId": "8d5adc18-6829-478f-8c20-4876bf723f52",
    "HTTPStatusCode": 200,
    "HTTPHeaders": {
      "x-amzn-requestid": "8d5adc18-6829-478f-8c20-4876bf723f52",
      "content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1",
      "content-length": "85",
      "date": "Wed, 12 Apr 2023 04:40:28 GMT"
    },
    "RetryAttempts": 0
  }
}
```

Comment: By event bus, I presume you mean the EventBridge service. Why do you want to put the event back? See [Improved failure recovery for Amazon EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/improved-failure-recovery-for-amazon-eventbridge/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are getting an EventId, your event was sent successfully. If you want to see it in CloudWatch Logs, [you will need to add a Rule to EventBridge with a CloudWatch Log Group as the target](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudwatch-log-group-eventbridge).

Or you should be able to see the event in CloudTrail (different from Cloudwatch Logs) [as described here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-logging-monitoring.html).

Comment: I needed to add the rule for the same event bridge. Rule which would satisfy the event that i am passing from lambda to event bridge. 
Set the rule in such a way that the target is cloudwatch log. 
It worked. Thank you for all your contribution.

Answer (score 0):

This can also happen as result of https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk/issues/186

where putting an event on a non-existent bus will still return a "successful" response.